# How to fill inputs using CMD (Command Prompt)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a certain program that i want to execute using CMD, but it asks for username and password.

And i want to pass those parameters during runtime using a batch script to run the exe file and type those texts.

This is what i have until now:

```
cd C:\Folder1\Folder2\

start Application.exe

:: here i want the batch file to type the username, press tab then write password and press enter
```

Comment: Batch can't interact with GUIs. You might want to try something like AutoHotKey instead.

Comment: How can i use it?

Comment: Is that program a GUI or a command line application?